# How to round the KPI values to 1 or 2 decimal or a whole number?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I created a "Status List", which take a SharePoint list as Source, I need to show the "Average" of the "% Completed" column. All other status record shows a normal looking value like "80%", "100%", but this one row, it has an average of value "77.8571428571429 %". (the calculation is correct since the total of % completed was 2180, and total number of rows was 28, the division comes out as 77.8571428571429 %).

How do I make this average value rounded to only show 1 or 2 decimals? or just rounded to a whole number?

I searched online, didn't find any help, anybody experienced this?